# Taylors Theorem Problem

Tags: real-analysis

Supose $f''$ exists on [a,b] and $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$, prove that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $|f''(c)| \geq \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|$. The way the problem is worded suggests to use Taylor's theorem, but I can't figure out how to actually construct the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the function $g\colon [-T, T] \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$
g(t) := f\left(t + \frac{a+b}{2}\right) - f\left(-t + \frac{a+b}{2}\right),
\qquad
t\in [-T, T], \ T:= \frac{b-a}{2}.
$$
The function $g$ is odd and $g'(-T) = g'(T) = 0$.
By Taylor's formula, there exists a point $\xi\in (0, T)$ such that
$$
0 = g(0) = g(T) - g'(T) T + \frac{1}{2} g''(\xi) T^2,
$$
i.e.
$$
g''(\xi) = - \frac{2}{T^2}g(T) = - 8 \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{(b-a)^2}\,.
$$
Let $x^\pm := \frac{a+b}{2} \pm \xi$. Since $g''(\xi) = f''(x^+) - f''(x^-)$, from the above equality we get
$$
f''(x^+) - f''(x^-) = -2 \cdot 4 \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{(b-a)^2}\,.
$$
On the other hand, if $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are real number such that
$r_1 - r_2 = 2r_3$, then necessarily $\max\{|r_1|, |r_2|\} \geq |r_3|$, hence the above equality gives
$$
\max\{|f''(x^+)|, |f''(x^-)|\} \geq 4 \frac{|f(b) - f(a)|}{(b-a)^2}\,.
$$

Comment: This was the answer my professor gave. What I am wondering is how you came up with the function

Comment: The estimate with $2 |f(b) - f(a)|/(b-a)^2$ is trivial. Hence the idea is to use the additional information $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$ in order to consider only half interval. This is achieved by means of the odd function $g$.